# I can't seem to solve this Table align error. Please help

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin {document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
Characteristic & DSPWM & DSVPWM \\
\hline
Boosting & - & - \\
\hline
DC Utilization & Less & 15% More \\
\hline
THD & More & Less \\
\hline
pf & Poor & Greater \\
\hline
Switching Loss & More & Less \\
\hline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}`
```

Comment: The problem here I think is the % symbol. Latex is commenting out the portion after %. How can I use the symbol as part of the document?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! "Please help" is not the best topic title. Please choose a short but good matching title and post your question in the question text. there I see only code below the title.

Comment: use `\%` (this is really a very basic command, and unrelated to table alignment)

Comment: use `\usepackage{siunitx}` and `\SI{15}{\percent} more`.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't you mean *this*:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin {document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
Characteristic & DSPWM & DSVPWM \\
\hline
Boosting & -- & -- \\
\hline
DC Utilization & Less & 15\,\% More \\
\hline
THD & More & Less \\
\hline
pf & Poor & Greater \\
\hline
Switching Loss & More & Less \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]